# Cronjob problems

Tags: bash, cron

I've written a small bash script to do a broadband speedtest using speedtest-cli.
After the script runs, it should write the output to a csv file.
I tested the script and everything works fine when calling it manually, however when the script is called by cron I can't get the correct output, namely, the download and upload speeds.

This is my cronjob:

```
0,30 * * * * speedtest_data/speedtest.sh
```

And this is the content of speedtest.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
#echo $(date | cut -d' ' -f5) $(echo ,) $(speedtest-cli --server 4440 | grep -n -e Download -e Upload | cut -d':' -f3 | cut -c1-6)

datetime=$(date +%d/%m/%Y';'%H:%M )
#time=$(date | cut -d' ' -f4)
speeds=$(speedtest-cli --server 4440)
download=$(echo "$speeds" | grep -n Download | cut -d':' -f3 | cut -c2-6)
upload=$(echo "$speeds" | grep -n Upload | cut -d':' -f3 | cut -c2-6)

echo "${datetime};${download};${upload}" >> /home/pi/speedtest_data/speeds.csv 2>> /home/pi/speedtest_data/speeds_err.log
```

To give and example, here's the output file where everything is written:

```
06/09/2014;19:25;61.80;20.13
06/09/2014;20:30;;
06/09/2014;21:00;;
06/09/2014;21:30;;
06/09/2014;22:00;;
```

The first line is the result of a manual execution of the script. The remaining are cron calls. Can anyone explain me why when the script is called via cron I can't get the download and upload speeds reading?

Comment: you probably need to add the path for `speedtest-cli` to either your crontab's PATH environment, or you can just add it in your script, like `speeds=$(/path/to/speedtest-cli ...)` . Good luck.

Comment: Tks @shellter, that was actually the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Also Whenever your writing a cronjob make sure you give the **ABSOLUTE** path name of your script instead of **RELATIVE** path name. In case if you use relative path name  then it may not work out for you.

Eg: 
    Absolute path - /var/www/html/scripts/db_backup.php 
    Relative path - scripts/db_backup.php

So let me give you an example : A cronjob to dump the current date time for every minute for all days irrespective of day of week.

```
crontab.txt
-----------

* * * * * /var/www/html/shell_scripts/currentDateTime.sh

currentDateTime.sh
------------------
#!/bin/bash

date >> /var/www/html/date_logs/dateTime.txt
```

Make sure you give the execute access premission for currentDatetime.sh. In linux machine you can do that by the following

```
chmod +x currentDateTime.sh

or

chmod 755 currentDateTime.sh
```

To register the cronjob we will do it by the following way. Here I have changed my directory where my **crontab.txt** had resided ie **/var/www/html/shell_scripts**. Then executed the following command.

```
/* To Register my cronjob to cron table */

crontab crontab.txt
```

Hope it might help someone. Happy Coding!